# Tabs: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am getting this warning

```
Warning: Tabs: `key` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it
```

I am already passing key in my component .don't know where I am doing wrong.

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-edison-g09nz?file=/src/App.js

```
<Tabs>
      {data.reduce((result, tabItem, tabIndex) => {
        result.push(<Tab {...getTabItemProps(tabItem, tabIndex)} key={tabIndex}/>);
        return result;
      }, [])}
    </Tabs>
```

**Tabs.js**

```
 <>
    <ul className="rc64nav" ref={tabsRef}>
      {tabsVisible.reduce((result, tabItem, tabIndex) => {
        result.push(tabItem);
        return result;
      }, [])}

    </ul>
    <ul>
    <hr/>
    <div>break</div>
      <hr/>
      {tabsHidden.reduce((result, tabItem, tabIndex) => {
        result.push(tabItem);
        return result;
      }, [])}
    </ul>
    </>
```

**Tab.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Tabs = ({ title,hidden }) => {
  return <li className={hidden ? 'hidden':'not-hidden'}>{title}</li>;
};

export default Tabs;
```

Comment: The error tells you which component has the problem (`Tabs`). The issue is in code that you did not include (line 63). The [`key` prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) is a special reserved prop. React uses it internally, but **does not** pass it down to the component like other normal props. This is why you get the error when accessing `key` in `Tabs`, because it's value will *always* be `undefined`

Comment: how to fix this error ?

Comment: Don't use the `key` as  a prop? If you need that data, pass it as another prop name and use it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-sid-l9753?file=/src/tabs.js.

What I changed:
I added a prop called `tabKey`. In `App.js`:

```js
const getTabItemProps = (tabItem, tabIndex) => ({
  title: tabItem,
  key: tabIndex,
  tabKey: tabIndex
});
```

I made `tabs.js` reference `tabKey` instead of trying to use `key` as a prop:

```js
const { tabKey = index } = tabItem.props;
```